# In my Python script for Maya, I need to check if a Logger argument is being passed in before I instantiate my own. How do I do that?

Tags: python, maya

I am creating a tool for Maya using Python and I need to check if logger is being passed in before I instantiate my own. How would I do that, and do I make a function to deal with the logging specifically? I guess there might be a higher tier one, like the Shotgun Maya one.

```
# this is a global variable
LOGGER = logging.logger(etc etc)
 
def function(logger=LOGGER):
```

Comment: Could you please give me a little feedback on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63008277/2749397) below?  I tried to guess what you want but I'm not sure and if it doesn't answer your question I'd prefer to remove it altogether. ፨ Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, the idiom is to assign a falsey value to a keyword argument and proceed to assign either the default (here, the global variable) or what you explicitly passed to the function:

```
LOGGER = ... # global instance
...
def f(..., logger=None):
    ...
    logger = logger if logger else LOGGER
    ...
...  
f(...)                              # uses LOGGER
f(..., logger=logging.logger(...))  # uses new instance
```

It's important to note that when you say `def f(..., var=something)` the assignment to `var` happens at compile time, so if you omit the assignment to the falsey value and directly say `def f(..., logger=LOGGER)` you have two problems ① if `LOGGER` is not bound at compile time you will have an error and ② if at runtime you change the global `LOGGER` your function will continue to use the `LOGGER` that was defined at compile time.